# Complexity to find cube root of n

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

The cube root of a natural number n is defined as the largest natural number m such that m^3≤n. The complexity of computing the cube root of n (n is represented in binary notation) is

(A) O(n) but not O(n^0.5)

(B) O(n^0.5) but not O((log n)^k) for any constant k > 0

(C) O((log n)^k) for some constant k > 0, but not O((log log n)^m) for any constant m > 0

(D) O((log log n)^k) for some constant k > 0.5, but not O((log log n)^0.5)

I am lost solving this previous year problem .Can any one help me to understand this question

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science, not practical programming. Try cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the algorithm used, which wasn't specified here?

Comment: I believe this quesion is worth being asked at cstheory.stackexchange.

Comment: migrate it to cs stackexchange.i have no option to migtate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer that question, you need to find upper and perhaps lower bounds on the complexity of finding an integer cube root m of n.  At least one upper bound is trivial, and rules out answers A and B:  m can be found in O(log n) time using binary search.

Also note that the input size is O(log n) because the minimum number of bits needed to represent an arbitrary n in binary notation is proportional to log n.  Because all bits of the number must be processed to solve the problem, θ(log n) is a lower bound on the time to solve the problem, and therefore the problem cannot be solved in time O((log log n)^w) [where w is some constant > 0] because that isn't O(log n).  Thus, answer C applies.

Comment: what is the difference it make if n is in unarry notation

Comment: @avi, the question says n is in binary notation, thus unary is irrelevant. However, if n were expressed in unary, then reading the input would cost θ(n) and processing at most O(log n) so total time is θ(n) and answer would be A.

Comment: why binary makes it complecated?? @jwpat7

Comment: @avi, perhaps recent edit to answer is more clear